# Can't call correct value from dropdownlist ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

So on my website, I have a changelog system that goes through the database querying what software he or she is assigned to and the latest changelog posts (much like a blog) but only for their assigned software.

I have created a web page to assign users to software (including roles etc.) however I cannot correctly call the DataValueField which is assigned during page load.

The binding table looks a bit like this (Comma separated list on here)

> BindingId, SoftId, UserId

The user's table is the default ASP.net identity table along with the user roles etc.

The software table, however, is assigned a unique id of the total number of rows plus 1.

The code I have is as follows (Standerd ASP.net code for dropdownlist control nothing special there)

```
Dim tbladap As New UserDataSetTableAdapters.SoftwareTableAdapter
    SoftDrop.DataSource = tbladap.GetAllData()
    SoftDrop.DataTextField = "SoftName"
    SoftDrop.DataValueField = "SoftId"
    SoftDrop.DataBind()
```

The issue is that SoftDrop always has a SelectedValue of 1. Just for reference the insert query is below

```
tbladap.Insert(tbladap.GetData().Rows.Count + 1, SoftDrop.SelectedValue, UserDrop.SelectedValue)
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In which event or method are you calling the Insert instruction?

Comment: @DavidBS have it called in an ASP update panel on a button click event. It saves to the database as the website creates a success alert in a div andI can also confirm the data in the SQL database, yet the selector always returns 1.

Comment: Try to save the selected value as soon the user choose one (the SelectedIndex event of Combo) into a hidden-field or even into a global variable, since I suspect what can be happening is due to the page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Poor research prior to asking the question.

All the controls loaded on page load and I didn't include:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack() Then
'Load the controls
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

try using like this

```
tbladap.Insert(tbladap.GetData().Rows.Count + 1, SoftDrop.SelectedItem.Value, UserDrop.SelectedItem.Value)
```

try using `SelectedItem.Text` too